# Show that there exists a subsequence $\{F_{n_{k}}\}$ which converges to uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, indefinite-integrals

Let $\{f_n\}$ be uniformly bounded sequence of functions which are Riemann-integrable functions on $[a,b]$ and define for $a\leq x\leq b$. $$ F_n(x)= \int_a^x f_n(t)dt.$$

Show that there exists a subsequence $\{F_{n_{k}}\}$ which converges to uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Here actually the basic problem is to show that $\{F_{n}\}$ is equicontinuous right. So can anyone write explicitly the reason why it is equicontinuous?

Comment: It sounds like you're being asked to show that the metric space of riemenn integrable functions on [a,b] with a given max bound is a (sequentially) compact metric space.

Comment: Right you are. Then I will use Ascoli Arzela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the following estimate : without loss of generality, assume $x \le y$.
$$
\left| F_n(x) - F_n(y) \right| = \left| \int_x^y f_n(t) \, dt  \right| \le \int_x^y |f_n(t)| \, dt \le M|y-x|
$$
where $M$ is the uniform bound of the $f_n$'s. Therefore the sequence $F_n$ is equicontinuous ; the uniform boundedness is given by the bound $M(b-a)$. You can apply Arzelà-Ascoli.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem).

As the $f_n$'s are uniformly bounded, say by $M$, then
$$
\lvert F_m(x)-F_m(y)\rvert\le\int_x^y \lvert\,f_m(t)\rvert\,dt\le M\lvert x-y\rvert,
$$
and hence $\{F_m\}$ is a uniformly equicontinuous family, which is also uniformly bounded, as
$$
\lvert F_m(x)\rvert\le M(b-a).
$$
Thus according to Arzelà–Ascoli theorem it has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Comment: I was faster :P sorryyy