# Let $F_n(x) = \int_a^bf_n(t)\ dt, x\in [a,b]$, show that there exists a subsequence $F_{n_k}$ which converges uniformly

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions defined in $[a,b]$, Riemann integrable. Let

$$F_n(x) = \int_a^bf_n(t)\ dt, x\in [a,b]$$
Show that there exists a subsequence $F_{n_k}$ which converges uniformly in $[a,b]$.

I tried to use some results, that say for example that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence, but it needs to be uniformly convergent.

I've also found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950159/show-that-there-exists-a-subsequence-f-n-k-which-converges-to-uniforml) similar question, but mine doesn't have the hypothesis of uniform boundedness. Does mine have a typo?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your question, since the RHS does not depend on $x$

Comment: @Momo yes, that seems essential

Comment: you should have $x$ instead of $b$ in the integral limits (both in the title and in the question)

Comment: More often than not, if you're trying to find a convergent subsequence that is uniformly convergent, you're going to be looking at Arzela-Ascoli. In order to apply this theorem, however, you need uniform boundedness as one of your hypotheses. Seems to me that your question is a merely a mistake away from the question you linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = n$ on $[0,1]$.  Then $F_n(x) = nx$.  No subsequence of that converges uniformly.